# Use regex in Java to extract specific parts of a String

Tags: java, regex

In the following string I want to extract the ids that come after **{\"company_id\":**   the part. The first in this case will be **4100**, and  there are two more farther away  **4045** and **2979**. All of this ids will be 4 digits. Sorry for including such a long string. The reason why I want to use regex and not some sort of **Json parser** is because the json is string  that is malformed.

```
String company = "[{\"company_id\":4100,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0},{\"company_id\":4045,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0},{\"company_id\":2979,\"data\":{\"drm_user_id\":572901936637129135,\"direct_status_id\":0,\"direct_optin_date\":0,\"direct_first_optin_date\":0,\"direct_last_optin_date\":0,\"direct_optout_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_date\":0,\"direct_last_form_id\":0,\"direct_last_promo_id\":0,\"anon_status_id\":600,\"anon_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_first_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_optin_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_optout_date\":0,\"anon_last_form_date\":1446132360498,\"anon_last_form_id\":101,\"anon_last_promo_id\":1002003,\"last_registration_date\":1446132360498,\"mp_status_id\":600,\"mp_control_state\":-1,\"mp_match_date\":0,\"mp_vs_version\":0,\"mp_initial_value_segment\":0,\"mp_id\":0,\"conversion_last_form_date\":0,\"conversion_last_form_id\":0,\"conversion_last_promo_id\":-1,\"last_message_date\":1446132368928,\"cg_version\":0,\"cg_version_date\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global\":0,\"num_anon_messages_global_date\":0,\"reg_creator_id\":576,\"reg_form_id\":101,\"reg_method_id\":1,\"reg_creator_type_id\":1},\"personal_data\":{\"version\":0,\"personal_data\":\"{}\",\"mdc_data\":{\"version\":0},\"custom_data\":\"{}\"},\"category_data\":{},\"campaignImpressions\":{},\"journeyStartDate\":0}]";
```

This  is what I have so far:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("company_id\\\\\":(\\d{4})");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(company);

while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)+"\n");
}
```

However this does not work,and I am not sure how to actually check that the number comes after this  **{\"company_id\":** specific part.

Comment: Your string looks like a json, you should better use available json parsers instead of regex

Comment: Ya. Use a JSON parser. Keep away from regexes as long as there are better alternatives :)

Answer (score -1):

Just a single backslash would be enough. `\"` should match a double quote.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"company_id\":(\\d{4})");
```